# Search text between different tags using XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and I need to find a phrase in an Html document. For example I have a document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>aaa Heading ilo araferi</h1>

Thats <p>My <b>first</b> paragraph.</p>
<p>My second paragraph.</p>
<p>My third paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to wrap `"Thats <p>My <b>first</b> paragraph.</p>"` inside a `span`. For that, I need to find all occurences with just text (no html tags). For example

> Thats My first paragraph.

In other words, I want the phrase `Thats My first paragraph.` to match `Thats <p>My <b>first</b> paragraph.</p>`

The problem is, I have no idea how to do the XPath query for this particular task. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `For that, I need to find all occurences with text`?? unclear...

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. I'm not native English speaker, sorry for any inconvenience :)

Comment: You may not wrap paragraph tags inside span tags in HTML. Use div tags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: updated, so the html will be still valid after span replacements

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;

namespace Test {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var markup = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h1>aaa Heading ilo araferi</h1>

    Thats <p>My <b>first</b> paragraph.</p>
    <p>My second paragraph.</p>
    <p>My third paragraph.</p>

    </body>
    </html>";
      var doc = new HtmlDocument();
      doc.LoadHtml(markup);
      var map = new List<HtmlNode>();

      var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()");
      var builder = new StringBuilder(markup.Length);
      for (var j = 0; j < nodes.Count; j++) {
        var node = nodes[j];
        builder.Append(node.InnerHtml);
        for (var i = 0; i < node.InnerHtml.Length; i++) {
          map.Add(node);
        }
      }

      var keyword = "Thats My first paragraph.";
      int index = builder.ToString().IndexOf(keyword);
      if (index >= 0) {
        var firstNode = map[index];
        var lastNode = map[index + keyword.Length - 1];
        var ancestor = Ancestor(firstNode, lastNode);
        if (ancestor != null) {
          while (firstNode != null && Level(firstNode) - Level(ancestor) > 1) {
            firstNode = firstNode.ParentNode;
          }
          while (lastNode != null && Level(lastNode) - Level(ancestor) > 1) {
            lastNode = lastNode.ParentNode;
          }
          if (firstNode != null && lastNode != null && ancestor == Ancestor(firstNode, lastNode)) {
            var span = doc.CreateElement("span");
            ancestor.ChildNodes.Insert(ancestor.ChildNodes.IndexOf(firstNode), span);
            int start = ancestor.ChildNodes.IndexOf(firstNode);
            int end = ancestor.ChildNodes.IndexOf(lastNode);
            for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
              var node = ancestor.ChildNodes[start];
              ancestor.ChildNodes.Remove(start);
              span.ChildNodes.Append(node);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      var writer = new StringWriter();
      doc.Save(writer);
      markup = writer.ToString();
    }

    public static HtmlNode Ancestor(HtmlNode a, HtmlNode b) {
      if (a == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("a");
      }
      if (b == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("b");
      }

      var parentsOfA = new List<HtmlNode>();
      while (a != null) {
        parentsOfA.Add(a);
        a = a.ParentNode;
      }

      while (b != null) {
        if (parentsOfA.Contains(b)) {
          return b;
        }
        b = b.ParentNode;
      }
      return null;
    }

    public static int Level(HtmlNode node) {
      int level = 0;
      while (node != null) {
        level++;
        node = node.ParentNode;
      }
      return level;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ondrej. I appreciate your help. There's one little problem though, wrapping the content in span would break <p> tag. span will be opened before p tag and will be closed before p tag. The problem is not as simple as it looks :(

Comment: @Davita - you're correct, to have the html valid after replacement, you need to find common ancestor and replace the span in HtmlNode way rather than simple text way. I've updated my answer accordingly.